# versioneer install fails with import error

Tags: python

versioneer install fails with import error:

```
$ versioneer install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/versioneer", line 7, in <module>
    from versioneer import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I would have expected that the `versioneer` command went through successful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to that another versioneer in the PYTHONPATH hides the real one:

```
>>> import versioneer
>>> versioneer.__file__
'/home/<user>/<repo>/versioneer.pyc'
```

Temporary unsetting the PYTHONPATH helps:

```
$ unset PYTHONPATH
$ versioneer install
versioneer.py (0.18) installed into local tree
...
```